# VBA macro HTTP request

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below method to make HTTP request in my VBA macro(copied from one
of the copied sites).

```
Function GetURLStatus(ByVal URL As String, Optional AllowRedirects As Boolean)

    Const WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects = 6


    If httpRequest Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set httpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
           If httpRequest Is Nothing Then
              Set httpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5")
           End If
        err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

   ' Control if the URL being queried is allowed to redirect.
   httpRequest.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = AllowRedirects       

  ' Launch the HTTP httpRequest synchronously
  On Error Resume Next
  httpRequest.Open "GET", URL + "x", False

  If err.Number <> 0 Then

    MsgBox err.Number
    ' Handle connection errors
    GetURLStatus = err.Description
    err.Clear
    Exit Function
 End If

 On Error GoTo 0

' Send the http httpRequest for server status
On Error Resume Next
httpRequest.SetTimeouts
httpRequest.Send
httpRequest.WaitForResponse
If err.Number <> 0 Then
    ' Handle server errors
    'PageSource = "Error"
    GetURLStatus = err.Description
    err.Clear
Else
    ' Show HTTP response info
    GetURLStatus = httpRequest.Status & " - " & httpRequest.StatusText
    ' Save the web page text
    'PageSource = httpRequest.ResponseText
End If

 On Error GoTo 0

 End Function
```

1. Can someone please explain what is the purpose of httpRequest.SetTimeouts and 
   httpRequest.WaitForResponse.
2. By default how much time will it wait for HTTP response, and what needs to
   modified to increase this waiting time

Answer (score 0):

For Q1,
the details you can read [Microsoft tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The SetTimeouts method specifies the individual time-out components of a send/receive operation, in milliseconds.
>
> The WaitForResponse method waits for an asynchronous Send method to complete, with optional time-out value, in seconds.

For Q2, It depend on many thing like your computer's network and the website's network.